# cakephp cakedc search plugin filter by name value and conditions

Tags: cakephp, cakedc, cakephp-search-plugin

I have a cakedc search plugin with cakephp 3.0 working fine, but would like to have more advanced search filters like:

```
city = 'Los Angeles';
city != 'Los Angeles';
city LIKE '%Angeles%';
city LIKE 'Los%';
city NOT LIKE '%Angeles%';
city NOT LIKE 'Los%';
etc...
```

So i'm looking to add 2 dropdown select and 1 text input to achieve this.

'city' would be in a dropdown of db fields.

=, !=, like %?%, like %?, not like ?% conditions would be a dropdown

'los angeles' search value would be typed in.

Comment: I'm sorry--I don't understand what it is you need help with...

Answer (score 0):

Figured out, might not be perfect but seems to work fine:

View:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('dbfield', ['label' => 'Field', 'options' => [''  => '', 'region' => 'Region', 'city' => 'City', 'keyword' => 'Keyword']]); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->input('dbconditions', [
    'label' => 'Condition',
    'options' => [
        ''  => '',
        'contains' => 'contains',
        'doesnotcontain' => 'does not contain',
        'beginswith' => 'begins with',
        'endswith' => 'ends with',
        'isequalto' => 'is equal to',
        'isnotequalto' => 'is not equal to',
    ],
]); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->input('dbvalue', ['label' => 'Value', 'class' => 'form-control input-sm']); ?>
```

Model

```
public $filterArgs = [
    'dbfield' => [
        'type' => 'finder',
        'finder' => 'conds0',
    ],
    'dbconditions' => [
        'type' => 'finder',
        'finder' => 'conds0',
    ],
    'dbvalue' => [
        'type' => 'finder',
        'finder' => 'conds',
    ],
];

public function findConds0(Query $query, $options = []) {

}

public function findConds(Query $query, $options = []) {

    if($options['data']['dbconditions'] == 'contains') {
        $conditions = [
            $options['data']['dbfield'] . ' LIKE' => '%' . $options['data']['dbvalue'] . '%',
        ];
    }
    if($options['data']['dbconditions'] == 'doesnotcontain') {
        $conditions = [
            $options['data']['dbfield'] . ' NOT LIKE' => '%' . $options['data']['dbvalue'] . '%',
        ];
    }
    if($options['data']['dbconditions'] == 'beginswith') {
        $conditions = [
            $options['data']['dbfield'] . ' LIKE' => $options['data']['dbvalue'] . '%',
        ];
    }
    if($options['data']['dbconditions'] == 'endswith') {
        $conditions = [
            $options['data']['dbfield'] . ' LIKE' => '%' . $options['data']['dbvalue'],
        ];
    }
    if($options['data']['dbconditions'] == 'isequalto') {
        $conditions = [
            $options['data']['dbfield'] => $options['data']['dbvalue'],
        ];
    }
    if($options['data']['dbconditions'] == 'isnotequalto') {
        $conditions = [
            $options['data']['dbfield'] . ' != ' => $options['data']['dbvalue'],
        ];
    }

    return $query->where($conditions);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I clean the code, only beacuse look a big code.
In other way, why you include an empty option in the Condition select input? not look better with a default search condition?
Saludos